# Java and .NET application communication

Tags: java, .net, asp.net, jakarta-ee

I don't think this is quite possible or if it is recommended to do... but is there a way to connect or comunicate or deploy Java and .NET application for method beside Web Services. I mean I understand there are Messaging server that allows Java application communicate to each other but I dont know if this can cross development environment, any suggestion about it or thoughts about this?

I'm limited to web and desktop environments.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I integrate Java with .Net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246096/how-can-i-integrate-java-with-net)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apache Thrift is a way to go. You will need to write a service definition like this:

```
serivce helloworld{
    string sayHello(1:string name)
}
```

Thrift then will generate RPC interface with network layer already implemented, It support many others language such as Java, C#, PHP, Python. Thrift support binary protocol over TCP/IP, so it's very fast.
for more, go to its wiki page http://wiki.apache.org/thrift/

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like [Apache ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/) which uses [JMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Message_Service) on the Java side and the [.NET Messaging API](http://activemq.apache.org/nms/) on the .NET side.

Answer (score 0):

We ended up writing our own implementation of Java-.Net communication protocol based on [Hessian](http://hessian.caucho.com/) (later added JSON as well), but Thrift is a valid option.

Answer (score -3):

The virtual machines (JVM vs CLR) are not going to talk to each other except through some OS level open standard.  Shared Files (yuck), Sockets and Web Services come to mind. There is nothing that would allow you to call a .net subroutine from java or vice-versa.

Comment: Can't you make .NET DLLs with C function signatures? If so then JNA should be able to load the DLL and invoke the .NET functions.

Comment: I think the a TCP socket based approach is the way. Why do you start your answer with "No!" ?

Comment: Web services and messaging protocols will work and are not "OS level".  There are plenty of java/.NET bridges out there